# Modifying an array that was created outside of a function inside a function

Tags: python

I coded a Tic Tac Toe game and right at the beginning of my code, I created a list that stores the X's and O's. So it's not inside any function. The code for the list is as follows: `board = [" " for x in range(10)]` I also wrote this to be able to play again after a game ends:

```
def playagain():
    while True:
        again = input()
        if again.lower() == "n":
            print("Goodbye!")
            quit()
        elif again.lower() == "y":
            board = [" " for x in range(10)]
            break
        else:
            print("Please enter Y or N")

while True:
    main()
    print("Again? \'Y\' or \'N\'")
    playagain()
```

But if I type "y" when it asks me if I want to play again, it just prints out the last result and asks if I want to play again even though it should recreate the board list and restart the game when I type "y". Here's the output it gives me:

```
Computer placed an 'O' in position  5 :
   |   |
 X | X | O
   |   |
-----------
   |   |
 X | O |
   |   |
-----------
   |   |
 O |   |
   |   |
Sorry, O's won this time
Again? 'Y' or 'N'
y
Welcome to Tic Tac Toe!
   |   |
 X | X | O
   |   |
-----------
   |   |
 X | O |
   |   |
-----------
   |   |
 O |   |
   |   |
Sorry, O's won this time
Again? 'Y' or 'N'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Add `global board` at the beginning of `playagain`

Comment: Basic hint: Learn more about functions. Use parameters and return values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must either declare `board` a global variable, as other commentators suggested, by writing `global board` in the beginning of the `playagain` function, or pass it as an argument into the function and modify it in-place.

Note, that in the latter case assigning a new list to this variable won't cut it - you'll need to actually modify the existing list:

```py
...
        elif again.lower() == "y":
            for i in range(len(board)):
                board[i] = " "
            break
...
```